# Is there anyway to get a lambda's return value by deduction without passing the argument types?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

Consider the following example:

```
template<auto const fnc>
struct dummy_s {

    typedef std::invoke_result<decltype(fnc), std::uint8_t >::type return_t;

};

int main() {
    dummy_s<[](std::uint8_t const& n) -> bool { return true ^ n; }>::return_t s = true; 
}
```

Is there anyway to get the return type without specifying `std::uint8_t` or whatever the number of arguments is, as template parameter as example.

Comment: What should be the result in the case of a generic lambda whose return type depends on the argument type(s)?

Comment: @BrianBi well, is not really relevant, but it should be the same type as the argument in that case, in the other hand, my main purpose is to specify the return type once using the lambda.

Comment: What @BrianBi is trying to say is "What if the lambda is something like `[](auto v) { if constexpr (std::is_same_v<decltype(v), int>) return ""; else return L""; }`? The return type is `const char*` if you pass an `int`, but it's `const wchar_t*` if you pass something else. Until you know what the argument is, you can't say what the return type is.

Comment: Usually this need points to bad and anti-generic design.

Comment: @RaymondChen, it is even worts than that. Even the function `[](auto v){return v;}` doesn't have clear single return type.

Comment: @alfC I was giving a counterexample to "it should be the same type as the argument in that case." In the case of `[](auto v){ return v;}`, returning the same type as the argument works by accident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a metafunction that gives you the type of the first argument

```
template<typename Ret, typename Arg>
auto arg(Ret(*)(Arg)) -> Arg;
```

and then decay the lambda `fnc` to a function pointer (using `+` say), that you pass to `arg`, and then use that in the typedef.

```
typedef std::invoke_result<decltype(fnc), 
                           decltype(arg(+fnc))>::type return_t;
```

This will only work for lambdas that don't capture anything, and that take a single argument.

---

You can also considerably simplify the typedef inside the struct by simply using `arg` directly like this

```
using return_t = decltype(arg(+fnc));  // using is cleaner than a typedef as well
```

This avoids using `invoke_result` entirely, and lets you define `arg` in a way that allows lambdas with multiple arguments to be passed to it

```
template<typename Ret, typename Arg, typename ...R>
auto arg(Ret(*)(Arg, R...)) -> Arg;
```

Here's a [demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/3bssje457)

Comment: Yeah, I thought the same, but there's a problem, what if the lambda has more than one argument?, I'd like if it'd be auto deducted.

Comment: @MindLerp If the lambda has more than one argument, but you only care about the first one, you could define `arg` as `template<typename Ret, typename Arg, typename ...R> auto arg(Ret(*)(Arg, R...)) -> Arg;`

Comment: well, I tried what you said with `dummy_s<[](std::uint8_t const& n, std::uint32_t) -> bool { return true ^ n; }>::return_t s = true;` , and literally doesn't even compile.

Comment: @MindLerp Ah, true. The `invoke_result` would need to be passed in the other argument types as well. Your question doesn't mention additional arguments at all though, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Yeah, I should clarify that.

Comment: @MindLerp Please don't add more constraints to a question once it's been answered. Anyway, I've added a simplification to the answer that should allow you to use multiple arguments https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/q436h8Pzc

Comment: Brilliant, I guess I have to train a bit more into the metaprogramming world, can you edit the answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @MindLerp Ok, I've edited the answer now, and added a demo, but please bear in mind what I said about changing the question after getting an answer. That's frowned upon by many members of the community

Comment: BTW, `Ret` can be used directly instead of `std::invoke_result` then.

Comment: Another constraint, lambda should not be generic.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment, each time I though I needed this feature I realized later I was going the wrong path. The reason is that as soon as the lambda is a template (`auto`) there is no hope to make it work.

More generally, if you don't have clue of the "universe" inputs of a function you don't really have a function, conceptually speaking.

If you think you still need it, you can use [Boost.TypeTraits](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/function_traits.html), lambda decay and function pointers.

```
#include<cstdint>
#include<boost/type_traits.hpp>

int main(){
    auto f = [](std::uint8_t const& n) -> bool {return true ^ n;};
    using f_return = boost::function_traits<decltype(*+f)>::result_type;
    static_assert( std::is_same<f_return, bool>{} , "!");
}
```

With any generalization of `f`, overload or templates, will not work.
You are really lucky that this sort of works because of a series of quirks in the language starting from the existence of monomorphic functions (inherited from C, pointer decay, etc). Conceptually, it is horrible.

Having said that, there is also a potential problem that is very sensitive to the version of C++ you are using, that is the use of lambdas in template (non-evaluated) contexts.

---

This is working solution based on *your* code.
It really works as is with certain combinations of compilers and flags, for example https://godbolt.org/z/5x684nfWc :

```
#include<cstdint>
#include<boost/type_traits.hpp>


template<auto fnc>
struct dummy_s {
    using return_t = typename boost::function_traits<decltype(*+fnc)>::result_type;

};

int main() {
    typename dummy_s<[](std::uint8_t const& n) -> bool { return true ^ n; }>::return_t s = true; 
}
```